# How to get value of bar in d3js bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot the bar graph and then sort it, and change the color of bars which are sorted. I have plotted the graph, have shown each steps. Since I am using a selection sort algorithm, bars from first to last will change colors in step. I am not able to change the color as I am using filtering and cannot estimate what to pass for the function in filter. Here is my attempt:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
<title>Bar chart with D3.js</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/da.css">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='layout'>
    <h2>Bar chart example</h2>
    <div class='container'>
        <svg class="chart" height="500" width="1000"/>
    </div>
</div> 
<p>Why this is not working?? </p>
</body>
<script>
var  data = [12,4,5,1,7,20,18,9,11,6,3,17,8,2];
// var data2=data;
var i=0;
var svg = d3.select("svg");
console.log();
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
var margin=50,
    width=svg.attr("width")-margin,
    height=svg.attr("height")-margin;
var Xscale = d3.scaleBand()
              .domain(data.map((e,i) => i+1))
              .range([0, width])
              .padding(0.2);
var Yscale=d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([0,d3.max(data)])
             .range([height,0]);  
var g=svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform","translate("+margin+","+margin+")");  
     g.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(Xscale).tickFormat(function(d){
                return d;
            }).ticks(data.length))
     ;

    g.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(Yscale).tickFormat(function(d){
         return d;
     }).ticks(10))
     .append("text")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", "0.71em")
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("value");


    g.selectAll(".bar")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("x", function(d,i) { return Xscale(i+1); })
     .attr("y", function(d,i) { return Yscale(d); })
     .attr("width", Xscale.bandwidth())
     .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height-Yscale(d); });
     // data2=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
     // data3=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
     // setTimeout(function(){return 1;},1000);
    // for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    //   var min=i;
    //   for(var j=i;j<data.length;j++){
    //     if(data[j]<data[i])
    //       min=j;
    //   }
    //   var temp=data[i];
    //   data[i]=data[min];
    //   data[min]=temp;
    //   update(data);


var s_sort_timeout=setInterval(function(){check();},1000);

function check(){
selection_sort(i);
update(data,i);
// if(i==data.length-1)
 // data2=data;
i++;
if(i>=data.length){
clearTimeout(s_sort_timeout);
// flash(-1);
}

}

function selection_sort(i) {
var min_index=i;
 // console.log(i,min_index)
for(var j=i;j<data.length+1;j++){
if(data[j]<data[min_index])
  min_index=j;
}
var temp=data[i];
data[i]=data[min_index];
data[min_index]=temp;
console.log("Swapped"+data[i]+" with "+data[min_index])
}

function flash(i) {
d3.selectAll(".bar")
.filter(function (d) {
  console.log("here " +Yscale(d)+" "+data[i]);
  return (false);
})
.style("fill","orange");

}

function update(data2,i){
svg.selectAll("bars").remove();
Xscale.domain(data2.map((e,i) => i+1)).range([0, width])
              .padding(0.2);
Yscale.domain([0,d3.max(data2)]);
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
              .remove().exit()
              .data(data2);
bars.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class","bar")
            .attr("x", function(d,i) { return margin+Xscale(i+1); })
            .attr("y", function(d,i) { return margin+Yscale(d); })
            .attr("width", Xscale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height-Yscale(d); });
flash(i);       

}
</script>

</html>
```

To keep short, I want to filter the bars which are with values data[i], refer flash() function. So  filer. something is my guess.
But after trying many things I get nothing. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter) says, `d3.filter` *Filters the selection, returning a new selection that contains only the elements for which the specified filter is true*.

When anonymous functions are used in d3, the letter `d` is usually used to refer to each of the elements in `data()` in each iteration. So if I undersant you right, your `flash` function should look like this:

```
function flash(i) {
  d3.selectAll(".bar")
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d == data[i];
    })
    .style("fill", "orange");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly. Thanks for the documentation as well.